# Determine integral for $\dot{u} = v$ and $\dot{v} = 2-u^2 - v^2 - u$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following system:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\dot{u} &= v\\
\dot{v} &= 2-u^2 - v^2 - u\end{array}
$$
I need to determine an integral for this system, so a function $k(u,v)$ which is constant along orbits. Normally this is a Hamiltonian, but I heard that we can't define a Hamiltonian for this system. The hint is to define $w = v^2$ and solve for $\tfrac{dw}{du}$, but I don't see where I can get an equation containing $\tfrac{dw}{du}$.

I tried writing this as a 1-dimensional system, so
$$
\ddot{u} - 2 + u^2 + (\dot{u})^2 + u = 0
$$
and multiplying this by $\dot{u}$, so we get
$$
\ddot{u}\dot{u} - 2\dot{u} + u^2\dot{u} + (\dot{u})^2\dot{u} + u\dot{u} = 0,
$$
I can integrate all the terms in this equation, except for the term $(\dot{u})^3$. Is there a nice way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w = v^2$,

$$\begin{align}
& \frac{dw}{du} = 2v\frac{dv}{du} = 2v\frac{\dot{v}}{\dot{u}}
=2(2 - u^2 - w - u)\\
\iff & \left(\frac{d}{du} + 2 \right) w  = 2(2 - u^2 - u)\\
\iff & \frac{d}{du}(e^{2u} w) = 2(2 - u^2 - u)e^{2u}\\
\iff & e^{2u} w = \int 2(2-u^2-u)e^{2u} du + \text{ const. }
                = (2-u^2) e^{2u} + \text{ const }\\
\implies& (u^2+v^2-2)e^{2u} = \text{ const. }
\end{align}
$$